# How to make a drop down menu in iOS

Tags: drop-down-menu, ios7, interface-builder

I'm new to iOS development. I am using a UINavigation Controller and i am trying to create a drop down menu using the interface builder. Please view image 
[image]

Comment: Okay. Sounds interesting.  Doesn't sound like a question though.

Comment: Thanks @nhgrif. I want to know how i can create a drop down menu using interface builder. i have never done it before.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can create this menu using the interface builder.  At least, probably not in the way you might mean.  Best case scenario, create a `XIB`, make it look like you want it to look, and when the menu button is pressed, load the view.

Comment: How do you create an XIB?

Comment: Use can use custom lib of [NIDropDown](https://github.com/BijeshNair/NIDropDown).

Comment: Try this
http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/a-simple-drop-down-list-for-iphone/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672298/ios-how-to-implement-a-drop-down-list-and-how-to-take-care-of-closing-it

Answer (score 0):

You could realize this by using UITableViews. But i would recommend to search on cocoaControls for existing projects. If you want to do it yourself you could look at this code f.i.

https://github.com/kiran5232/KDropDownMultipleSelection

Answer (score 0):

Check out this pod - https://github.com/nmattisson/DropdownMenu

As for me it's one of the best implementations available, easy integrated via Storyboards